# Display Top result by region

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

Table Orders

```
OrderID    Region    CustomerID    SalesPersonID
  1         North      01               001
  2         North      12               002
  3         North      33               002
  4         North      55               002
  5         North      21               001
  6         North      11               002
  7         North      33               004
  8         North      15               002
  9         East       23               005
 10         East       01               005
 11         East       12               005
 12         East       33               007
 13         East       55               005
 14         East       21               006
 15         East       11               006
 16         East       33               006
 17         East       15               007
 10         East       34               007
```

I am looking to display the sales person with most orders in each region. So my end result should look like:

```
Region     SalesPerson    Orders
North         002           5
East          005           4
```

How can I retrieve this information?

Comment: Be great to see what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions - if your database, which you did not tell, supports them:

```
select Region, SalesPersonID, Orders
from (
    select 
        Region, 
        SalesPersonID, 
        count(*) orders, 
        rank() over(partition by Region order by count(*) desc) rn
    from orders
    group by Region, SalesPersonID
) t
where rn = 1
```

`rank()` allows top ties, if any. You can use `row_number()` if you want just one result per region, even if there are ties.

Answer (score 0):

1. Consult the totals by seller and by region.
2. With the previous totals calculate the maximum sale by region and with this totals the related sellers must be determined

   ```
   with Totales as 
   (
     select Region,SalesPersonID,count(1) As Totales 
     from sales
     group by Region,SalesPersonID
   )
   ,MaxRegion as
   (
     select Region,max(Totales) As Totales
     from totales
     group by Region
   )
   select MaxRegion.Region,Totales.SalesPersonID,MaxRegion.Totales 
   from MaxRegion 
       inner join Totales on MaxRegion.Region=Totales.Region and MaxRegion.Totales=Totales.Totales
   ```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/537e8/12)

Keep in mind that if you have two sellers with the same number of maximum sales, they will be included in the query.